# Suite fails to run when accesing the excel --Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have created a small Junit framework(Selenium) with 4/5 junit testcases and when we run this the last testcases fails to execute

4.In the fourth testcase we are creating an excel and entering some information to the same.(runs succesfully)
5.In the fifth testcase we are retrieving the data from that excel and updating it again.(But here the test skips.)

The fifth testcase runs succesfully when run independently.Where are we go wrong?

I have not provided the code as it is huge!
Please let me know in case you need it for sure

thanks in advance

Comment: Code is huge ! Atleast put the code at which it is getting skipped.

Comment: Worked fine after doing some R&D,thanks for raising ur hand